# In the Lydian Chromatic Theory, what does the "H" mean next to scale degrees?

Tags: theory, lydian-chromatic-concept

referring to "Chart A" of the Lydian Chromatic Concept Theory -
[image: lcc]

what does the "h" mean next to the Vh, IIh, and Ih scale degrees?  I understand that they are Alternate Modal Tonic Degrees, but I haven't found anywhere in the book that clearly explains it.

Comment: Are you asking what the "h" means, or are you asking what a "alternate and conceptual modal tonics" are?

Comment: I'm asking what the "h" means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The letter "h" following these roman numerals (as in Vh, IIh, IIIh and
> VIIh) indicates their status as conceptual modal tonic degrees of the Lydian
> Scale.<sup>1</sup>

> <sup>1</sup> h = Horizontal state of the LC Scale: duality of non-final to final. v = Vertical state of the LC Scale: unity of chord and scale.

George Russell, *The Lydian Chromatic Concept of Tonal Organization*, 4th edition (Brookline, MA: Concept Publishing Company, 2001), page 116.